# Monkeyrunner.sleep() always Error sending press event

Tags: android, eclipse, monkeyrunner

i using android MonkeyRunner do some test

every time run Monkeyruuner.sleep() will FAIL

like this

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER', 'DOWN_AND_UP')
MonkeyRunner.sleep(10)
device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER', 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

in the second

```
device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER', 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

always fail

```
[main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Error sending press event: KEYCODE_ENTER DOWN_AND_UP
```

please help 
thank
'
Thanks all reply!

but even using time.sleep() or MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP always have wrong

my scores code

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner
import time 
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT', device.DOWN)
device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT', device.UP)
time.sleep(2)
device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT', device.DOWN)
device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT', device.UP)
time.sleep(2)
device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT', device.DOWN)
device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT', device.UP)
time.sleep(2)
```

in the three time down , up always wrong

log

```
120718 09:50:51.744:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Error sending press event: KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT DOWN
120718 09:50:51.744:S [main][com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
120718 09:50:51.744:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
120718 09:50:51.744:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
120718 09:50:51.744:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Your key code is as per the API.

However, I had similar issue with MonkeyRunner.sleep function (Could be a bug itslef in certain android builds).

As a workaround I use time.sleep function as mentioned below.

```
import time
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER', 'DOWN_AND_UP')
time.sleep(10)
device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER', 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

Thank You.

Comment: The API documentation is incorrect. device.press() will default to using down_and_up if an invalid option is given. This is why strings will work. Try doing device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER', 'DOWN') and then device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER', 'UP'). That should behave like a single down_and_up however you will get two presses of the enter key. However doing device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER', MonkeyDevice.DOWN) and then device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER', MonkeyDevice.UP) behaves normally.

Comment: Also, it looks like the API documentation was corrected. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not failing because of `Monkeyruuner.sleep()`, in `device.press` `'DOWN_AND_UP'` should actually be `MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP`